# Why malloc triggers a breakpoint?

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm writing a program as a school project but I keep running into "Critical error detected c0000374" or "...  has triggered breakpoint" I've tried to debug but with no luck also I noticed that sometimes it will run other time it will crash on random malloc. Below is my code it should generate linked list for MOVIES and for every movie linked list of ACTORS. I don't have much experience with C. Please help.

```
typedef struct meno {
    char meno[100];
    char priezvisko[100];
}NAME;

typedef struct herec {
    struct meno meno;
    int rok_narodenia;
    struct herec *dalsi;
}ACTOR;

typedef struct film {
    char meno[100];
    struct herec *herec;
    int rok_vyroby;
    struct meno meno_rezisera;
    struct film *dalsi;
}MOVIE;

MOVIE* nacitaj() {
    FILE* file;
    int i = 1;
    file = fopen("filmy.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("SUBOR SA NEPODARILO OTVORIT");
        return NULL;
    }

    MOVIE* film = malloc(sizeof(MOVIE*));
    MOVIE* head = film;
    MOVIE* film_temp = NULL;
    ACTOR* herec = NULL;
    ACTOR* herec_temp = NULL;
    char temp,temp2;
    film->dalsi = NULL;
    while ((temp = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
        if (temp != '*') {
            //pre film
            if (film->dalsi != NULL) {
                herec->dalsi = NULL;
                herec = NULL;
                herec_temp = NULL;
                film = film->dalsi;
                film_temp = NULL;

            }
            if(film_temp == NULL){
                film_temp = malloc(sizeof(MOVIE*));
                film->dalsi = (MOVIE*)film_temp;
            }

            film->meno[0] = temp;
            while ((temp = fgetc(file)) != '\n') {
                film->meno[i] = temp;
                i++;
            }
            i = 1;
            fscanf(file, "%d\n%s %s\n", &film->rok_vyroby, film->meno_rezisera.meno, film->meno_rezisera.priezvisko);
            herec = (ACTOR*)malloc(sizeof(ACTOR*));
            film->herec = (ACTOR*)herec;
        }
        if (temp == '*') {
            //pre herca
            if (herec != NULL && herec->dalsi != NULL) {
                herec = (ACTOR*)herec->dalsi;
                herec_temp = NULL;
            }
            if (herec_temp == NULL) {
                herec_temp = malloc(sizeof(ACTOR*));
                herec->dalsi = (ACTOR*)herec_temp;
            }
            fscanf(file, "%s %s %d\n", herec->meno.meno, herec->meno.priezvisko, &herec->rok_narodenia);
        }

    }
    film->dalsi = NULL;
    fclose(file);
    return head;
}
```

Comment: OT: regarding; `printf("SUBOR SA NEPODARILO OTVORIT");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  This is easily done with `fprintf(, stderr, "your error message\n" );`  however when the error is from a C library function, like `fopen()` should also output (to staderr) the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The function: `perror( "your error message" );` which handles both these activities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`malloc(sizeof(MOVIE*));` is wrong as you allocate only as many bytes as the size of the pointer not the size of the struct.

Then you dereference the fields of the struct - so you access the memory which does not belong to you.

you need to allocate as many bytes as struct requires

```
malloc(sizeof(MOVIE));
```

or in this particular place - but you have the same error in other places in your code

```
MOVIE* film = malloc(sizeof(film*));
```

The second method (object in sizeof instead of type) is considered better as you can change the type of the object without changing the type in your sizeofs.

Answer (score 2):

Your malloc should be :

`MOVIE* film = malloc(sizeof(MOVIE));`

sizeof(data structure), not the pointer.